# I am having a strange output when using to_csv

Tags: python, dataframe

I am having a strange output when using to_csv
The code I am running is as follows.

```
import  pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()
symbol_='SHFE.rb1906'
side_='long'
dtStr='2019-03-20 9:30:01.600'
df.loc[0,'symbol']=symbol_
df.loc[0, 'side'] = side_
df.loc[0, 'dtime'] = dtStr
with open('riskWarned.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=f.tell()==0,index=False)
```

The output of the program is as follows:
[image]

Why is there a blank line in the middle of the output?

edit:

I am not sure if this screenshot can be displayed, I will copy the text content again.

```
symbol  side    dtime

SHFE.rb1906 long    30:01.6
```

And there is  a blank line in the middle of the output

edit 2:
I opened the csv file with Notepad and the screenshot was posted below.

[image]

The output is normal from this content of the notepad

Comment: Maybe your spreadsheet program is adding that blank line?  Post the raw contents of the csv file.

Comment: @ John Gordon, The csv file is created by the instruction open('riskWarned.csv', 'a')

Comment: I can see how the file is created.  I asked for the contents.

Comment: I'm suspicious that there're n/a values in your dataframe.

Comment: @ John Gordon,Not sure what the contents you refered to  is . I have re-posted screenshots and text of the output to the question.

Comment: I ran your code on my Mac, and I don't get a blank line.  I get two lines, each containing three quantities separated by commas.  Are you on Windows?  That seems to be where strange line behavior always happens. - It opens up fine for me, without the blank row, in both Mac Numbers and Excel.

Comment: What @JohnGordon is asking for, I believe, which would be very helpful, is your output as plain text.  In other words, bring your output file up in a plain text editor, copy out the contents, and paste it into your question.

Comment: @ Steve,Yes, I run the code on windows 10. It doesn't seem to be a code issue, thank you.

Comment: @Steve,I just understood what you mean. I opened csv with Notepad and posted the screenshot to the question area.

Comment: Why are you opening the file in `a` mode?  Do you expect the file to already exist?